# Where is classpath for windows 7 java weka

Tags: java, classpath, weka, libsvm

I want to use libsvm in weka but it says there is no libsvm in weka classpath

How do i find this class path in Windows 7 x64

I also installed x64 version of weka

I don't see any classes in weka folder

I already downloaded libsvm jar file

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This web page shows how to set the classpath  http://weka.wikispaces.com/CLASSPATH.
The procedure it gives for Win32 will work on Windows 7.

Here is a slightly longer version of what's on that page:

- Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables
- Select CLASSPATH under System Variables and click Edit...
- Add a semicolon to the end followed by the full path of libsvm.jar
- click OK, 3 times
- restart Weka and, everything else being OK, it will work.

Answer (score -1):

CLASSPATH should have the lib folder path of JDK