# error in installation of libSVM

Tags: java, weka, libsvm

I am trying to  activate the libSVM on my weka3.6 on windows 7, but there is an error mentioned that the libsvm classes not in CLASSPATH! I tried to add the classpath in advanced system settings. but still it doesn't work. I have also doubt about where exactly should I save the libsvm.jar file. is there any body to help me please?

Thanks,
Aram

Comment: What IDE you are using? Adding the classpath in your system setting won't help. You need to set Java Classpath: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Please post the classpath entry on environment variable and location of the file on your system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is classpath for windows 7 java weka](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714988/where-is-classpath-for-windows-7-java-weka)

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to have trouble you could download the developer version of Weka- [Weka 3.7](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html)

Provided in this version is a "Package Manager".  The package manager **will download and install libsvm for you**.  Directions for using the package manager can be found [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+the+package+manager%3F).